# In what order does gulp process tasks?

Tags: gulp

I'm a bit confused about the order in which tasks are completed using Gulp. Allow me to explain.

In gulpfile.js, I have all my required dependencies followed by a set of tasks.

The basic template of each sub task is

```
gulp.task('compress:customName', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/folder/file.js', 'app/folder/file.js'])
        .pipe(gp_concat('app.customName.min.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir));
});
```

Then, I have a task that rules them all

```
gulp.task('compress:all', [
    'compress:customName1', 
    'compress:customName2', 
    'etc...'
], function() {});
```

Then one more master task runner (just using compress:all for this example)

```
gulp.task('master', ['compress:all'], function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/*.js')
        .pipe(notify("COMPRESSION COMPLETE"));
});
```

OK...that's the basic setup...now to talk about the order in which these tasks appear to be completed per the command line results.

```
[11:06:44] Using gulpfile C:\PATH\TO\PROJECT\gulpfile.js
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName1'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName2'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName3'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName4'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName5'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName6'...
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:customName7'...
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName1' after 108 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName6' after 93 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName5' after 132 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName4' after 139 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName3' after 233 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName2' after 245 ms
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:customName7' after 381 ms
[11:06:44] Starting 'compress:all'...
[11:06:44] Finished 'compress:all' after 6.64 µs
[11:06:44] Starting 'master'...
[11:06:44] gulp-notify: [SO EXAMPLE : Gulp Builder] COMPRESSION COMPLETE
[11:06:44] Finished 'master' after 40 ms
```

How can 'master' be the last task to start and starts AFTER 'compress:all'?

Why are the Finished tasks displaying in such a random order?

Why is it that 'master' is said to have completed in only 40 ms when it should be waiting for all the sub-tasks it invokes to respond before considering itself complete?

Comment: I don't see `compress` task in your example. Did you mean `master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can 'master' be the last task to start and starts AFTER 'compress:all'?

Dependencies are run before actual task is started. 'compress:all' is dependency for 'master'.

> Why are the Finished tasks displaying in such a random order?

Dependencies are run in parallel i.e. when one finishes depends only on the time it takes to complete one.

> Why is it that 'master' is said to have completed in only 40 ms when it should be waiting for all the sub-tasks it invokes to respond before considering itself complete?

Dependencies are not included in the completion time of a task.

---

**"deps – An array of tasks to be executed and completed before your task will run."**

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps

Comment: Are the dependencies run in the order they are added to the task?

Comment: No, they are all started at the same time ~ run in parallel.

Comment: Okay...I see. I read on the same page that one may return a promise instead of a stream. Do you have any advice on using this in order to gain more control over a sequence of operations?

Comment: I don't use promises. If you need tasks in certain order use [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence). Parallel/series will be easier in gulp 4.

Comment: I also found that I could manage a series of events using the gulp-merge tool...especially when I needed to compile then minify...ensures one is done before doing the other.